# How to get specific value from Web Service

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I am using Global Weather Web Service in my asp.net application http://www.webservicex.net/globalweather.asmx?op=GetWeather.

The code works fine but I want to get only temperature to be displayed on label.

```
ServiceReference1.GlobalWeatherSoapClient client = new  ServiceReference1.GlobalWeatherSoapClient("GlobalWeatherSoap");
string weather = client.GetWeather("Karachi Airport", "Pakistan"); 
Label1.Text = weather;
```

Label control is showing complete data provided by service (i.e Date, Time, Country and city name etc)

Comment: You are getting string in XML?

Comment: `Karachi Airport, Pakistan (OPKC) 24-54N 067-08E 22M Oct 21, 2015 - 01:25 AM EDT / 2015.10.21 0525 UTC from the E (100 degrees) at 6 MPH (5 KT):0 3 mile(s):0 91 F (33 C) 57 F (14 C) 31% 29.91 in. Hg (1013 hPa) Success`

Comment: getting above in browser in continuous line.

Comment: The link you have provided is returning in XML form

Comment: It Returns an XML. u can put it in an `xmlDoc` and then Get the `<Temperature> ` Node

Comment: Yes that's what i wanted to tell you.

Comment: how to put in `xmlDoc` >

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the link you have provided it returns that string in XML form.

**So Use it as below:**

```
  var doc = XDocument.Parse(weather);  //use .Load if you are pulling an xml file.
  var location = doc.Root.Element("Location").Value;
  var Temperature = doc.Root.Element("Temperature").Value;
  Label1.Text = Temperature;
```

Just Like above you can get another values too e.g. DewPoint, RelativeHumidity etc

```
var DewPoint= doc.Root.Element("DewPoint").Value;
var RelativeHumidity = doc.Root.Element("RelativeHumidity ").Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can get it like this also

```
 string weather = client.GetWeather("Karachi Airport", "Pakistan"); 
    XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
    xmlDoc.LoadXml(weather );
    XmlNodeList elemlist = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("Temperature");
    string temp= elemlist[0].InnerXml;
```